# Composer install/update takes more than 1GB of disk space?

Tags: composer-php

I'm trying to set up a newly cloned application.
I had 4 GB of hard disk space left originally.

Then I ran `composer update` and it took forever and finally ended with an error that I ran out of disk space.

Not knowing how to free up more space from the previous sesison, I closed all my applications and restarted. I only had 2.4 GB to start with this time.

So I tried running `composer install` this time. But it continues to eat up my disk space. I stopped it manually when I dropped below 1GB.

Is this normal? There isn't a lot of stuff to include.
And, how can I free up the disk space that composer took up?

This is the stage composer was stuck in for a long time:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
```

This is my composer.json file:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
        "mremi/url-shortener": "~1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
    "way/generators": "~2.0",
        "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "~1.11",
        "symfony/var-dumper": "~2.6",
        "raveren/kint": "dev-master"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php"
        ],
        "files": [
            "app/vendors/spg/SPGHelpers.php",
            "app/vendors/spg/SPGGenPopularity.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "SPG\\":"app/vendors/spg"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the reason was I had `xdebug` on.
Turning it off solved the problem.

And the disk space that was eaten was by `xdebug`, not `composer`.
Going into `/private/var/tmp` and `rm cachegrind.out.*` removed all the profiling cache `xdebug` generated.